# Comparing a String with a Char

Tags: java

I have been trying to create a Temperature Converter in java using 3 function for the conversion of the Fahrenheit, Celsius, and the print out of the results.  The code works, but for reason I am comparing a String with a Char, making the expression never equal. I am really confused about this.  Please I need your help, Thank you.

**TemperatureConverter:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class TemperatureConverter {


  public static double convertToCelsius(double degrees ){
    double celsius = (5*(degrees - 32)/9);
    return celsius;
  }


  public static double convertToFahrenheit(double degrees ){
    double fahrenheit = (9*( degrees/5 ) + 32);
    return fahrenheit;
  }



  public static String getOutput(char units, double degrees) { 
    if ((units == 'F') || (units == 'f'))
    {
      String output = " ";
      output = degrees + " F = " + convertToCelsius(degrees);
      return output;
    }
    else if ((units) == 'C' || (units) == 'c' )
    {
      String output = " ";
      output = degrees + " C = " + convertToFahrenheit(degrees);
      return output;
    }
    if(!(units == 'F' || units == 'f' || units == 'C' || units == 'c'))
    {
      String output = ("Unknown units - cannot do calculation\n" + 
                    " - next time enter either \'F\' for Fahrenheit or \'C\' for Celsius.");
      return output;
    }
    return "";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double degrees;
    char units;

    System.out.println("Enter a temperature in degrees (for example 29.6): ");
    degrees = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter 'F' (or 'f') for Fahrenheit or 'C' (or 'c') for Celsius: ");

    units = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println(getOutput(units, degrees)); 
  }
}
```

**TemperatureConverterTest:**

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

/**
 * A JUnit test case class.
 * Every method starting with the word "test" will be called when running
 * the test with JUnit.
 */
public class TemperatureConverterTest extends TestCase {
  public static final double EPSILON = 0.0001;
  public void testConvertToCelsius() {
    assertEquals(0.0, TemperatureConverter.convertToCelsius(32), EPSILON);
    assertEquals(100, TemperatureConverter.convertToCelsius(212), EPSILON);
    assertEquals(-17.7777777778, TemperatureConverter.convertToCelsius(0), EPSILON);
    assertEquals(-40, TemperatureConverter.convertToCelsius(-40), EPSILON);
  }

  public void testConvertToFahrenheit() {
    assertEquals(32, TemperatureConverter.convertToFahrenheit(0), EPSILON);
    assertEquals(100, TemperatureConverter.convertToFahrenheit(37.7777778), EPSILON);
    assertEquals(0, TemperatureConverter.convertToFahrenheit(-17.7777778), EPSILON);
    assertEquals(-40, TemperatureConverter.convertToFahrenheit(-40), EPSILON);
  }

  public void testGetOutput() {
    String output = TemperatureConverter.getOutput('C', 0.0);
    assertEquals("User inputs 'C' and 0.0 degrees", "0.0 degrees C = 32.0 degrees Fahrenheit.", output);

    output = TemperatureConverter.getOutput('c', 0.0);
    assertEquals("User inputs 'c' and 0.0 degrees", "0.0 degrees C = 32.0 degrees Fahrenheit.", output);

    output = TemperatureConverter.getOutput('F', 0.0);
    assertEquals("User inputs 'F' and 0.0 degrees", "0.0 degrees F = -17.77777777777778 degrees Celsius.", output);

    output = TemperatureConverter.getOutput('f', 0.0);
    assertEquals("User inputs 'f' and 0.0 degrees", "0.0 degrees F = -17.77777777777778 degrees Celsius.", output);

    output = TemperatureConverter.getOutput('m', 0.0);
    assertEquals("User inputs 'm' and 0.0 degrees", "Unknown units - cannot do calculation\n" + 
                " - next time enter either 'F' for Fahrenheit or 'C' for Celsius.", output);
  }
}
```

Comment: it looks like you are comparing char to char - nothings wrong I think.

Comment: Try equals() the normal java comparing nightmare

Comment: @rekire Primitives don't have an `equals` method - they're not objects

Comment: you could rip out your if(!(units == F or f or etc and make it an 'else'

Comment: Seems to work for me, do you have a runnable example that demonstrates your problem...

Comment: You said in your question "the code works."  What exactly is your problem then?

Comment: I am comparing a String with a Char, making the expression never equal, and not passing the Test.

Comment: @sotirios The test file, make an test on the code to see if the output is correct.

Comment: No, show us _your_ test.

Comment: @sotiris I updated the failure error. Don't know if it will help.

Comment: @mcalex What are you trying to say? Please be more specific.

Comment: No, give us a small reproducible, ie. that we can run, code example. Right now we can only guess what you are doing.

Comment: Alright, I just posted the entire code.

Comment: @Germblaster I downloaded your example (although you really should have posted it here) and it ran fine. You say the code works, and it does. You say you are comparing a string to a char, but you aren't -- I don't see that anywhere. Can you *specifically describe* how your *expected* results differ from your *actual* results?

Comment: @jasonC I know, but I am not suppose to have a comparing String with a Char.

Comment: @Germblaster your last branch of the if statement (ie if units != F or f or C or c) is the same as saying if units == anything else.  So, you could replace everything from 'if' up to (but not including) the '{' with 'else'.  The last branch would then read 'else {'

Comment: @Germblaster Please tell me exactly which line of code is comparing a String with a Char.

Comment: @Germblaster Next time post *all of the relevant code*. You initially posted a link (don't make it hard for others to help you, please), then you removed the link but didn't post your test code (and so *only* the people who saw your previous edit *and* followed the link had enough info to diagnose the problem). I've added your test code. Next time don't keep your code a secret. You would have gotten an answer in seconds had you posted the relevant info the first time around. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to make your function as the following:

```
  public static String getOutput(char units, double degrees) { 
    if ((units == 'F') || (units == 'f'))
    {
      String output = " ";
      output = degrees + " degrees F = " + convertToCelsius(degrees) + " degrees Celsius.";
      return output;
    }
    else if ((units) == 'C' || (units) == 'c' )
    {
      String output = " ";
      output = degrees + " degrees C = " + convertToFahrenheit(degrees) + " degrees Fahrenheit.";
      return output;
    }
    if(!(units == 'F' || units == 'f' || units == 'C' || units == 'c'))
    {
      String output = ("Unknown units - cannot do calculation\n" + 
                    " - next time enter either \'F\' for Fahrenheit or \'C\' for Celsius.");
      return output;
    }
    return "";
  }
```

it passed the test in my computer..

hope it helps..

Comment: Yes, Thank you. This worked perfectly. Will inspect what I didn't do right.

Comment: you're welcome.. you definitely learned _a lot_ today..
don't rush and organize your question.. =)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't comparing strings and chars, it's that the expected output doesn't match the given output.

You need to add the extra 'guff' in your expected answer to the output result.

Add the starred lines (**) to the 'F' branch and similar code to the 'C' branch

```
if ((units == 'F') || (units == 'f')) {
    **String tempType = "Fahrenheit";**
    String output = " ";
    output = degrees + " F = " + convertToCelsius(degrees);
    **output = output + " degrees " + tempType**
    return output;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are *not* comparing strings with chars. You have this:

```
if ((units == 'F') || (units == 'f'))
```

But `'F'` (in single quotes) is a *character* literal, not a string. If it were `"F"` (double quotes) then it would be a string:

```
char a = 'F';     // <- this is a character 
String b = "F";   // <- this is a string
char c = 'XYZ';   // <- this is invalid code!
String d = "XYZ"; // <- this is a string
```

I think you are getting confused about `'F'` -- it's a character, not a string. So, your code looks fine.